# why my highchart code is not working?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this in my drilldown event of highcharts which works right.

```
if (!e.seriesOptions) {
    var s=e.point.name;
    var chart = this,
        drilldowns = {
         'SAR': {
                name: 'SAR',
                data: yearData,
            }

        },
        series = drilldowns[e.point.name];

    chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series);                                       
}
```

but when I replace string 'SAR' with e.point.name

```
if (!e.seriesOptions) {
    var s=e.point.name;
    var chart = this,
        drilldowns = {
         s: {
                name: s,
                data: yearData,
            }

        },
        series = drilldowns[e.point.name];

    chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series);
}
```

it does not show any drilldown data where in e.point.name has got string 'SAR' in it.

Comment: can you create a fiddle please?

Comment: How your data and chart configuration does it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a JS-Object like you intent to do:

```
var s = 'SAR',
drilldowns = {
  s: {
    name: s,
    data: [],
  }
}
```

will create an object `drilldown` with the key `s` instead of `SAR`:

```
{s: {name: "SAR", data: [] }}
```

You can however use a String for a key with bracket notation:

```
var s = 'SAR', 
drilldowns = {};

drilldowns[s] = { 
  name: s, 
  data: []
}
```

will create an drilldown-object with the right keys for you:

```
{SAR: {name: "SAR", data: []}}
```